# visual studio still debugging after I close the window

Tags: visual-studio

As of yesterday my Visual Studio continues debugging even after I close the program window.

So now I have to close the window and stop debugging before I can go back to the code, whereas before it just automatically stopped debugging without me having to touch anything.

I didn't intentionally change any settings, but why is this happening?

Comment: Are you starting any threads?

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes. It may be due to Visual Studio starting background tasks that have not finished yet.

When it does happen, simply open the Windows Task Manager, look for the process `devenv.exe` and kill it.

Comment: It's still doing it even after restart, and if I end that process Visual Studio terminates. Then I re-open it and I have the same problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to say with so little information, I think. Are you debugging a Windows Service project perhaps? Is your code generating a lot of threads? Are you executing unit tests? ...

Comment: Yea, something strange happening. It's just a generic wpf project. Now I'm getting an error:

Comment: "Unable to copy the obj\x86\Debug\project.exe file to bin\Debug\project.exe. the process cannot access bin\Debug\project.exe because it is being used by another process.

Comment: I have, but problem keeps coming up, even after it seems to have been fixed.

Comment: It's times like these that I really love programming!

Comment: In Visual Studio, have you tried Cleaning your solution, then re-building before you run your project?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your program is still running even after you've closed the main window. Try pausing the debugger after you've closed the main window and see what it is doing.